# Converting a putty ssh tunnel to a command line one

Tags: ssh, putty

I am trying to convert below putty configuration to a `ssh` command.

[image: Putty Configuration]

I do not understand the `mysql5:3306` part. What is this `mysql5` element and what is the corresponding command line option in the `ssh` command on Linux?

Comment: It's ssh tunneling: after the ssh, when you connect to port 3306 on your machine, you'll actually be connecting to port 3306 on the remote machine. 3306 is the default port for MySQL. You need something like `ssh -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 user@remote`

Comment: @BarryCarter I know that. I just try to figure out the `ssh` command on Linux that is equivalent to above configuration. Where do I put the `mysql5` part in the `ssh -L ...` command?

Comment: You shouldn't need the `mysql5` bit at all unless mysql5 is the name of the machine you're connecting/forwarding to?

Comment: @BarryCarter Actually, I don't know. The hosting provider lists a bunch of information (like user, ports, passwords ...) and states how to configure putty with it. The `mysql5` bit is called the "ssh tunnel name".

Comment: Well, try using it as the remote machine name and see what happens?

Comment: @BarryCarter Thanks for your input, I have figured out something, although I do not completely understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently,

`ssh -N -L 3306:mysql5:3306 user@remote`

worked to establish the ssh tunnel.